# How do I get certain value from an array from this API?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

http://roblox.plus:2052/inventory?username=joxxi

It shows one big long array.

The first part is:

```
{"id":107484852,"username":"Joxxi","bc":"BC","rap":643
```

how do I like ignore everything but the 643

I am using the api in a php script like this:

```
echo "<td><object height='20' width='100' data='http://roblox.plus:2052/inventory?username=".$row['username']."'/></td>";
```

right now its just echoing the array

Comment: why aren't you using `file_get_contents`?

Comment: Do you want the result, `643`, in your `<object>` `data` attribute, or just as a js var or php var?

Comment: not sure i am not the best with php.

Comment: If you have an array with the json data ,thenon doing alert(a.rap) witll give 643, where a is the array. https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/rwnkjq9q/

Answer (score 0):

Try file_get_contents

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://roblox.plus:2052/inventory?username='.$row['username']);
echo json_decode($page,true)['rap'];
```

Comment: is my concatination right?

Comment: $page = file_get_contents("http://roblox.plus:2052/inventory?username='". $row['username'] . "'");

Comment: for some reason it doesnt show 643 it shows 0 when echoed

Comment: Omg it works thank you so much!

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple do

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://roblox.plus:2052/inventory?username=joxxi');
```

Then transform result into associative array

```
$row = json_decode($result, true);
```

Later you can echo but before make sure row is not a collection of array if so return first one

```
if (count ($row)) {
    $row = $row[0];
}
echo $row['rap']
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I've also noticed there is a difference in execution time comparing curl and file_get_contents. You can also use below curl code to get the desired data.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://roblox.plus:2052/inventory?username=joxxi');
$resultCurl = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($resultCurl);
echo $obj->rap;
```